# Get Hashtable/Map from Spark Dataframe Column stored as binary(serialized Hashtable) in SQL Server 2016 using Apache Spark 2.4

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, hashtable

In one of the Legacy Application, In DB - SQL Server 2016, We have a Table - Measures

it has 15+ Columns, one of the column is **binary**

[image]

When I load into Spark and print the Schema, its **binary**

```
scala> jdbcDF.printSchema()
root
 |-- measurementValues: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- measure: string (nullable = true)
```

Looks like, they have used **Hashtable**, serialized it and stored into Table Column as binary

---

I am trying to de-serialize the same back into Hashtable (or) Map (or) Some Collection to able to convert into JSON Format while doing ETL Operations

Can anyone help here? I tried to convert the binary to string, still of no use :(

```
val convertToString = udf((a: Array[Byte])=> new String(a))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  def deserializeBinary = udf((x: Array[Byte]) => {
    val stream: InputStream  = new ByteArrayInputStream(x);
    val obs = new ObjectInputStream(stream)
    val stock = obs.readObject.asInstanceOf[util.Hashtable[String, String]]
    stock
  })
```